# Complete measures on Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

$\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal{X}}\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}}\newcommand{\cl}{\mathrm{cl\ }}$
Let $(\X, \tau, \B)$ be a Hausdorff (topological) space (with topology $\tau$) as well as a measure space (with sigma-algebra $\B$ , not necessarily the Borel sigma-algebra), and let $\mu : \B \to [0, 1]$ be the (probability) measure. Also assume that $\B$ is complete under $\mu$ (contains all $\mu-$null sets) and that for all compact $K \subseteq \X$, $K \in \B$.

**Question:** Given $A \in \B$, is it true that the closure of $A$, $\cl A \in \B$ ?

Comment: If $\mu$ is regular then this is true but not otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! A proof would be very helpful. :)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy regularity is only defined when $\mu$ is defined on all Borel sets and this is not necessarily the case here.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What I meant was that for any $E \in \mathcal B$ and $\epsilon >0$ there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\mu (E\setminus K) <\epsilon$.